# Win10 %temp% (AppData\Local) directory seems to overflow & autodelete some folders periodically, which corrupts browser extensions and other software

Tags: windows, temporary-files, appdata

I recently briefly changed my temp directory in an attempt to fix a problem with Python and Anaconda, but it's back to the default now (C:\Users\Rob\AppData\Local). **I'm almost certain that's the original cause of the problem.** It seems unlikely that malware is involved, and I don't run any shady .exe downloads. This happens every week or so.

Sometimes Wox and sometimes Obsidian need to be reinstalled, because their executables are located in AppData\Local (%temp%). Same with Brave's (Chrome-based) extensions, which prompt me to "repair now". I've even lost my game progress in Returnal. There seems to be no pattern to the folders which get deleted.

C:\ has 73 gigabytes of storage available. I've checked SMART data (wmic diskdrive get status) and got the result "OK" for each disk. chkdsk C: returns: "Windows has scanned the file system and found no problems. No further action is required."

My system environment variables' TEMP and TMP are both set to C:\WINDOWS\TEMP. My user environment variables' TEMP and TMP are both set to C:\Users\Rob\AppData\Local.

As of writing, I had this happen this morning, and the Local folder is currently 3.87 gigabytes.

Anyway, I'd like to know why this happens and how to fix it. This seems like it's some simple built-in Windows thing responding incorrectly to my abuse of the env variables.

Comment: Look at S.M.A.R.T data -- is drive dying? Also, do a complete scan with chkdsk, and use DISM and SFC to be sure OS is OK.

Comment: What is the question. Why does it happen or Whats the solution?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: So little information.  Have you run chkdsk /F on the drive?  What does the S.M.A.R.T. data tell you?

Comment: Added more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I mistakenly reset my `%TEMP%` and `%TMP%` variables to `AppData\Local` instead of `AppData\Local\Temp`.